# How to scale the solution of NDSolve?

Tags: plotting, scaling

I need to scale the numerical result obtained from `NDSolve` in the x-direction, while the y-direction (function value) remains the same. For example,

```
sol = NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], t] == 0.5 D[u[x, t], x, x] + u[x, t] D[u[x, t], x],  
u[-Pi, t] == u[Pi, t] == 0 , u[x, 0] == Sin[x]}, u, {t, 0, 2}, {x, -Pi, Pi}]

Plot[u[x, 2] /. sol, {x, -Pi, Pi}, PlotRange -> {{-Pi, Pi}, All}]
```

[image]

Now, how can I scale (i.e. compress) the solution to within an interval of [-1,1], but the function values of the corresponding scaled x-positions remain unchanged? Thank you!

Comment: Like this? `Plot[u[x Pi, 2] /. sol, {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: @AlexTrounev Yes, something like that. Could you generalize it, say, scale from [-L,L] in `NDSolve` to [-m, m] in `Plot`. I will accept it then. Thank you!

Comment: `Plot[u[x L/m, 2] /. sol, {x, -m, m}, PlotRange -> All]`